# In C# can I use a specific implementation of a generic based on the type (T) used

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I am trying to create a class structure in WPF/MVVM/Entity Framework that is as generic as possible. I am using Prism & Unity.  Really though I don't think any of that matters unless somehow I can use Prism/Unity in the solution.

I have a system that is setup and works perfectly, until I need to run code that is specific to the Type(T).

What I would really like is to somehow have the system uses the non-generic version of a class if type T has a derived class that matches, otherwise I want it to use the generic version.

In a super watered down example I have a base class:

```
public class BaseClass<T>
{
    public T MyObject;

    protected virtual int GetErrorCount()
    {
        int errorCount = 0;

        if (MyObject == null)
            errorCount++;

        return errorCount;
    }
}
```

And a subclass:

```
public class StringClass : BaseClass<String>
{
    protected override int GetErrorCount()
    {
        int errorCount = base.GetErrorCount();

        if (MyObject != null && MyObject.Length < 5)
            errorCount++;

        return errorCount;
    }
}
```

And an Implementation Class:

```
public class ImplementationClass<T>
{
    public BaseClass<T> MyBaseObject;

    public ImplementationClass()
    {
        // If T is a string I want to use StringClass instead of the base
        // And it should happen automagically
        MyBaseObject = new BaseClass<T>();
    }
}
```

I have a few ideas for working around this involving convoluted switches or tossing the logic (of data for the logic) on the POCO class but that's not what I want to do.

I have tossed around the idea of using a Dictionary and some lookup class that gets used whenever I need to resolve the actual type - but really that what Prism does, so I would think I could use that somehow... Just can't figure it out.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this as generically as possible?

---

Got it figured out, any feedback on this? What do I need to watch out for?

Solution (allows for MyBaseObject to be changed too):

```
public static class HelperExt
{
    internal static IEnumerable<Type> GetInhiritingTypes(this Type fatherT)
    {
        return fatherT.Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(fatherT) && !t.IsAbstract);
    }
}

public class ImplementationClass<T>
{
    private BaseClass<T> _myBaseObject;
    public BaseClass<T> MyBaseObject
    {
        get { return _myBaseObject; }
        set
        {
            Type instType = typeof(BaseDataViewModel<T>).GetInhiritingTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().Contains(typeof(T)));
            if (instType != null)
                SetProperty(ref _myBaseObject, (BaseClass<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(instType));
            else
                SetProperty(ref _myBaseObject, value);
        }
    }

    public ImplementationClass()
    {
        // If T is a string I want to use StringClass instead of the base
        // And it should happen automagically
        MyBaseObject = new BaseClass<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: might it make sense to use aggregation instead of inheritance?

Comment: I'm not sure how I could aggregation here, at least not while solving the issue and without losing the generic implementation.

Comment: Your use of generics seems pointless to me. But you can declare multiple private members, one for each type you might want to use, and then use the one you deem appropriate based on the type of T.

Comment: How do you create instances of `ImplementationClass<T>`?

Comment: That's being done through Prism/Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with some reflection, first this helper function:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInhiritingTypes(this Type fatherT)
    {
        return fatherT.Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(fatherT) && !t.IsAbstract);
    }
```

Then:

```
Type genericType = typeof(string);
Type typeToInstantiate = typeof(BaseClass<String>).GetInheritingTypes().FirstOrDefault(t=>t.GetGenericsArguments().Contains(genericType));
if (typeToInstantiate != null)
    MyBaseObject = (BaseClass<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeToInstantiate);
else
    MyBaseObject = new BaseClass<T>();
```

But there is very little "safety" in using a method like this. You might as well write a factory function that takes a class name and instantiates an instance of that class.

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work. I've broken it down into smaller steps. I can see that the `typeToInstantiate` has the correct Parent Type (i.e. `StringClass`) but `GetGenericArguments()` returns an empty array. Any ideas.

Comment: Eh... Figured it out. Looks like I needed to do `instTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().Contains(genType))`  <-- the key be BaseType.